Generate a Series of Numbers
I am trying to generate random serial numbers in PostgreSQL with some conditions.

The numbers need to start with the same 3 letters, YAK.
After YAK, there needs to be 8 random digits.
I only need to do 10 iterations of this.

I know I should try to start with generate_series() but can I use RANDOM() in there at all like I probably would for python?

There's a problem with your question.  If you do, for example, SELECT "YAK"+FLOOR(RANDOM()*10000+10000); (which isn't quite correct), the problem is you'll get a different random number every time.  That's almost never what you want.

@TimRoberts Isn't that what is expected from random numbers?

Yes, but when this has been asked before, they wanted each record to get assigned a random ID, but keep that ID list forever.

I definitely want a different random number every time.  Also, I keep getting a syntax error using that code. Should generate_series() be in there somewhere?

This question is similar to: Generating a random 10-digit ID number in PostgreSQL. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@TimRoberts To repeat the same set of random numbers use setseed(): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html

@FrankHeikens That's not the point, of course.  If you happen to read the third record, you want it to have its previously assigned random ID number.

You seem to have all the building blocks, you just need to put them together:

generate_series can be used in the from clause to generate 10 rows
For each of these rows, you can use random and multiply it by 100,000,000 to generate a random number between 0 and 99,999,999.
Then, you just need to pad that number up to eight digits and slap a 'YAK' before it:

SELECT CONCAT('YAK', LPAD(FLOOR(RANDOM() * 100000000)::TEXT, 8, '0'))
FROM   GENERATE_SERIES(1, 10)

SQLFiddle demo

It might happen once in a billion years to have a duplicate, yet better  select DISTINCT concat('YAK', lpad(floor(random() * 100000000)::text, 8, '0')) from generate_series(1, 20) LIMIT 10;. Worst case you'll have less than 10 rows.

You can implement a function to randomize, like
CREATE FUNCTION myrandom(varchar, integer, integer) RETURNS varchar
    AS 'select concat($1, LPAD(FLOOR(RANDOM() * $2)::TEXT, $3, ''0''))'
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
    
select myrandom('YAK', 100000000, 10) from generate_series(1, 10);

Parameters:

prefix
pool size
character length

Explanation: You select a randomized number based on pool size, LPAD resolves the character length and you concatenate the result to the prefix.
Fiddle: https://sqlfiddle.com/postgresql/online-compiler?id=174f8022-049b-40b1-9ad9-b2fbf79c5edd
